# Why was SHIELD not responding to Darcy's calls?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world

The out-of-universe explanation is of course that this is a Thor movie and hence the Avengers intervening was not possible: please don't give me that.

What is the in-universe explanation of SHIELD not turning up to help Thor battle Malekith? I'm not sure if SHIELD would have been welcome at Asgard, but if they had stayed in contact they could have helped in the final battle on Midgard.

Will this be revealed in a future movie?

Comment: Possibly not a dupe, but very much related: [Where were the Avengers during Iron Man 3?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35318/where-were-the-avengers-during-iron-man-3)

Comment: Perhaps we’ll find out in the next Captain America film? That takes place a year after Thor 2 – perhaps the events of the Avengers crippled SHIELD in such a way that they didn’t have the resources to assist Darcy et al.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not an in-universe answer, but my instincts say that S.H.I.E.L.D. is like a very high authority figure in the Marvel-verse. For this kind of high authority, a call from a stranger doesn't garner that much attention. From the "Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D" TV series, it is clear that S.H.I.E.L.D has their own work too, so they might be too busy in doing something else that they don't have the time to respond to some stranger's call.

The scene of Darcy mentioning S.H.I.E.L.D. is just like mentioning the presence of a cinematic universe. During IM3 the media and fans always ask where the other Avengers are and where S.H.I.E.L.D. is. So this is like a trick to avoid the same question for Thor 2.

There is an episode of Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D ("The Well") connecting to Thor: The Dark World but I am unaware of its plot.

Comment: Darcy isn't exactly a stranger to them. She was there when S.H.I.E.L.D took Jane/Erik's work in New Mexico. The episode "The Well" is loosely tied to Thor: The Dark World, in that it involves Asgardians and begins in the same library from the movie, but it has no direct plot or character involvement connections to the movie.

Comment: I don't think Darcy have any good interaction with S.H.I.E.L.D. , Which make her trustable to S.H.I.E.L.D.

Comment: I'm not saying they're best friends or that Coulson/Fury would have her on speed dial, but S.H.I.E.L.D knows who she is, and that she has a connection to Thor. They took her work and her iPod - there is no way S.H.I.E.L.D is not going to have a file on her.

Comment: see the new edit. May it clear my point more.

Comment: In the Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D episode, they seem to be aware of what happened, but we only pick up after the battle. Very possibly they did receive her call but did not respond in time to be useful. However, I don't recall this being explicitly stated one way or the other, as the show does not follow dispatch or HQ or intelligence gathering, only the one field team.